# One website page with several controllers controlling views

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm building my own MVC Framework in order to learn how it works.

I have now a basic Framework Folder, with a Model, Controller and View class. Which implements basic classic for each purpose.
For example model class contains methods for DB queries, DB connection...

This is a short view of the website's tree :

```
index.php
Controller
|-ControllerHome
|-ControllerStory
|-ControllerConnection
Model
|-Story
|-User
View
|-ViewHome
|-ViewStory
|-ViewConnexion
|-template.php
Framework
|-Model.php
|-Controller.php
|-View.php
|-Router.php
```

I have a main Controller Router.php which calls the right Controller knowing post data.

**My problem** is that I can't find a proper (I main clean and reusable) way to use several controller in order to build my webpage with several views.

Each webpages are made of the main content and the Connexion box, so every pages are supposed to use ControllerConnection.

Currently I'm calling ControllerConnection inside ControllerHome and ControllerStory but doing so, I need to write the same lines of code on every Controller. Is it wrong to call a controller in an other controller?

Comment: I think you mean `ControllerConnection`. I don't think you need a controller for a database connection - controllers tend to be for an area of a web application. It can be broad like 'users' or narrow like 'user registration'. You could have a base controller class in which a method is used to return a connection. Or you could separate out the controller from your business logic and move the connection to a service class (since querying the database is related to your logic rather than the workings of the controller).

Comment: ControllerConnexion is a class which allow the user to login and logout with viewConnection and the form inside. The problem would be the same for a website with an advertising area, a login area, a quick search area and a content area.

Every area need a controller and this controller will be used in every page, but the "content" Controller is not the same on every page.